# Select a random file and move with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, bots

i'm trying to fix a bug with my twitter bot, basically, there is an array with all the filenames of the folder, then selects one randomly and posts it, but sometimes posts the same image again, how can i fix it?

here is the code

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    Twit = require('twit'),
    set = require(path.join(__dirname, 'set.js'));
    //array of files
    files_memes = require(path.join(__dirname, 'files.js'))

var currentdate = new Date();
var upl = "Subido: "
          + currentdate.getHours() + ":"
          + currentdate.getMinutes()+ " hs.";

var setMin = 10;
var T = new Twit(set);

function random_file(){
  var allFiles = (files_memes)//array
  return allFiles[Math.floor(Math.random() * allFiles.length)];
}

var filename = (random_file());
var imgPATH = path.join(__dirname, '/memestorage/queue/' + filename);


//image selection and upload
function upload_random_image(){
  console.log('Opening file...');
  var image_path = imgPATH,
      b64content = fs.readFileSync(image_path, { encoding: 'base64' });

  console.log('Uploading file...');
  T.post('media/upload', { media_data: b64content }, function (err, data, response) {
    if (err){
      console.log('ERROR');
      console.log(err);
    }
    else{
      console.log('File loaded!');

      T.post('statuses/update', {
        media_ids: new Array(data.media_id_string)
      },
        function(err, data, response) {
          if (err){
            console.log('Error!');
            console.log(err);
          }
          else{
            console.log('Tweeted!');
            console.log(upl);
            console.log('Next tweet in ' + setMin + ' min.');
          }
        }
      );
    }
  });
}

//timer

setTimeout(
      upload_random_image,
        0
    );
setInterval(
      upload_random_image,
      1000*10
    );
```

I've tried with

```
...
var filename = (random_file());
var pfile = ("posted"+random_file());
var imgPATH = path.join(__dirname, '/memestorage/queue/' + filename);
var postedFile = path.join(__dirname, '/memestorage/posted/' + pfile);
fs.rename(imgPATH, postedFile, function(err) {
  if ( err ) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
});

//image selection and upload
function upload_random_image(){
  console.log('Opening file...');
  var image_path = imgPATH,
      b64content = fs.readFileSync(imgPATH, { encoding: 'base64' });
...
```

But posts the same image over and over again, or sometimes gives this error message:

```
fs.js:640
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\memesbot\memestorage\queue\645 (2).jpg'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:508:33)
    at Timeout.upload_random_image [as _onTimeout] (D:\memesbot\memes.js:29:23)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
```

Hope someone can help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code seem to be generating random file at start (`var filename = (random_file());`) but not at run of `upload_random_image()`.

So, file is selected randomly one and `upload_random_image` is called multiple times with `setInterval`

Solution:

Move below line inside the method `upload_random_image`

```
var filename = (random_file());
var imgPATH = path.join(__dirname, '/memestorage/queue/' + filename);
```